# iBeacon ranging, Android, Minor always the same

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I've made an app for Android that detects iBeacons. It's based on the 'Find The Monkey example that uses the Ibeacon library from Radius networks.

The app has been working fine until this morning when it started to only recognise 1 of my beacons (i have maybe 6 in the office).

The code that it loops through will be familiar to most who have played with iBeacons:

```
void RangingBeaconsInRegion(object sender, RangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Beacons.Count > 0)
            {
                var beacon = e.Beacons.FirstOrDefault();

                var minor = beacon.Minor;

                Console.WriteLine ("Minor IS .... " + minor);


                switch((ProximityType)beacon.Proximity)
                {
                case ProximityType.Immediate:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Beacon FIRED with minor " + minor);
                    showCouponMessage();
                    break;
                case ProximityType.Near:
                    UpdateDisplay ("You're getting warmer (near)", Color.LawnGreen);

                    break;
                case ProximityType.Far:
                    UpdateDisplay("No Beacons here (far)!!", Color.Blue);
                    break;
                case ProximityType.Unknown:
                    UpdateDisplay("I'm not sure how close you are to the Beacon (unknown)", Color.Red);
                    break;
                }
```

When it stopped working, i added the Console.Writeline statement to try to understand which beacon it was picking up and why it wasn't seeing any others. Looking at the console window, it appears that in fact it does 'see' the other beacon's Major and Minor IDs, but chooses to only identify the beacon with a Minor of '2'.

Here's a section of the output window:

```
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 742 32001 accuracy: 1.440510248595126 proximity: 2
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 14640 7849 accuracy: 5.0375909818338265 proximity: 3
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.findthemonkey_android/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()
[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null
[BluetoothAdapter] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
Thread started:  #15
Minor IS .... 2
Thread finished:  #15
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 14640 7849 accuracy: 2.629927091577368 proximity: 2
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 742 34001 accuracy: 0.6951160689284792 proximity: 2
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.findthemonkey_android/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()
[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null
[BluetoothAdapter] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
Thread started:  #16
Minor IS .... 2
Thread finished:  #16
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 14640 7849 accuracy: 2.629927091577368 proximity: 2
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.findthemonkey_android/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()
[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null
[BluetoothAdapter] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
Thread started:  #17
Minor IS .... 2
Thread finished:  #17
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.findthemonkey_android/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()
[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null
[BluetoothAdapter] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
Thread started:  #18
Thread finished:  #18
Minor IS .... 2
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 14640 7849 accuracy: 5.447335444796175 proximity: 3
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0 0 accuracy: -1.0 proximity: 0
[IBeaconService] iBeacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :f7826da6-4fa2-4e98-8024-bc5b71e0893e 742 32001 accuracy: 1.440510248595126 proximity: 2
[Callback] attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.findthemonkey_android/com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor}
[BluetoothAdapter] stopLeScan()
[BluetoothAdapter] startLeScan(): null
[BluetoothAdapter] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
Thread started:  #19
Minor IS .... 2
```

As you can see, it does 'see' the beacons with other Minors, but seems to only want to identify the 1 beacon i have with a Minor of '2' and continually outputs that to the console window.

Any ideas what is happening here? Is this something to do with the Android Bluetooth stack bug? I'm running Android 4.4.4 on a Nexus 4, and i thought that bug was resolved in 4.4.

Comment: Your code would appear to only process the "first or default" given to you by the scanner; why don't you iterate through all of those it gives you?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Seems I completely missed that!